# React Native using custom hooks with Redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, google-oauth

I have worked with React Native for a number of years now, but I am currently taking a course on some other concepts I have not used before.

I am currently learning about Redux, and integrating it in React Native. The course I am following is using Redux to manage authentication with Facebook. However, I have no plans to use Facebook Auth in any of my foreseeable apps, but rather Google.

One of my existing apps, makes use of a custom hook, where I handle Google Sign In, but this is called directly in the component I need, and I store the token in context. I know that hooks can only be called in the body of a function component, and I am struggling to get this working with Redux.

I have already setup my reducer and store, and am working on the action itself.

My Google custom hook looks something like this:

```js
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useGoogleSignIn = () => {
  const useProxy = __DEV__ ? true : false
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    androidClientId: '',
    iosClientId: '',
    expoClientId: '',
  });
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === 'success') {
      setAccessToken(response.authentication.accessToken);
    }
  }, [response]);

  const promptMobileGoogleSignIn = () => promptAsync({ useProxy, showInRecents: true });
  const isGoogleClientAvailable = !!request;

  return {
    response,
    accessToken,
    isGoogleClientAvailable,
    promptMobileGoogleSignIn,
  };
};

export default useGoogleSignIn;
```

My action

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { GOOGLE_LOGIN_SUCCESS, GOOGLE_LOGIN_FAIL } from './types';

export const googleLogin = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('google_token');

  if (token) {
    // User has completed Google Login
    dispatch({ type: GOOGLE_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: token });
  } else {
    const handleGoogleLogin(dispatch)
  }
};

const handleGoogleLogin = async dispatch => {
  // Handle the sign in, and get the accessToken
  const response = ...
  if (response?.type === 'success') {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('google_token', response.authentication.accessToken);
    dispatch({ type: GOOGLE_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: response.authentication.accessToken });
  } else if (response?.type === 'cancel') {
    return dispatch({ type: GOOGLE_LOGIN_FAIL });
  }
}
```

Like I mentioned, I am new to Redux, so I apologise for any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a working solution for my above question. I am still not all that clued up with Redux, and yet to see and appreciate the benefits. However, I changed the approach I previously used for signing in with Google, by using the newer `@react-native-google-signin/google-signin` opposed to `expo-auth-session/providers/google`.

At the moment, my implementation is very minimal, but I removed the custom hook I created, and now my action looks as follows:

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { GOOGLE_LOGIN_SUCCESS, GOOGLE_LOGIN_FAIL } from './types';
import { GoogleSignin, statusCodes } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export const googleLogin = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('google_token');

  if (token) {
    dispatch({ type: GOOGLE_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: token });
  } else {
    handleGoogleLogin(dispatch);
  }
};

const handleGoogleLogin = async (dispatch) => {
  GoogleSignin.configure({
    androidClientId: Constants.expoConfig.extra.googleAndroidClientId,
    iosClientId: Constants.expoConfig.extra.googleiOSClientId,
  });
  try {
    await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
    await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    const { accessToken } = await GoogleSignin.getTokens();
    if (accessToken) {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('google_token', accessToken);
      dispatch({ type: GOOGLE_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: accessToken });
    } else {
      return dispatch({ type: GOOGLE_LOGIN_FAIL });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
      // user cancelled the login flow
      console.log('User cancelled the login flow');
    } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
      // operation (e.g. sign in) is in progress already
      console.log('Operation is in progress');
    } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
      // play services not available or outdated
      console.log('Service not available');
    } else {
      // some other error happened
      console.log(error);
    }
    return dispatch({ type: GOOGLE_LOGIN_FAIL });
  }
};
```